# Problem of Mathematical Induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $n!\leq 2^{-n}(n+1)^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and equality holds if and only if $n=1$.

Comment: @KittyL I tried using mathematical induction.

Comment: @maths_student:  It would greatly improve your question to detail the attempt at mathematical induction.  That way Readers can see where your try ran into a difficulty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AM GM inequality $$\dfrac{r+(n+1-r)}2\ge\sqrt{r(n+1-r)}$$

Set $r=1,2,3,\cdots, n-1,n$

Comment: Could you please help me in proving that  if equality holds then $n=1$.

Comment: @maths_student, The above equality holds iff  $r=n+1-r\iff 2r=n+1$  But If $n\ge2,$  There will be at least one $1\le r\le n$ such that $2r\ne n+1\implies$ $$\dfrac{r+(n+1-r)}2>\sqrt{r(n+1-r)}$$